# I am trying to do Application with Spring MVC + Hibernate framework and messed up with org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDAO com.emusicstore.app.HomeController.productDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.emusicstore.dao.impl.ProductDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Drive]

Comment: Seems like an error with the jdbc driver can You post your properties file where jdbc driver is defined

Comment: You're getting this exception because you've got `com.mysql.jdbc.Drive` class instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or is it a typo while copy pasting?

Comment: This issue got resolved after changing mysql driver class name Thanks Bunti